# Why shinydashboard changes the corner of a numericInput from round to 90 degree?

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have the following two scripts creating one `numericInput` and one `selectInput` fields. One is in `shiny`, and the other is in `shinydashboard`. I also created shinyapps.io link to these two examples.

My question is why `shinydashboard` changes the corner of the `numericInput` to be 90 degrees? Please see the screenshots. In example 1, both input fields have round corners.

[image]

However, in example 2, the corner of the `numericInput` becomes 90 degrees.

[image]

It would be great if someone can help me understand this behavior and develop a way to make all the corners either round or 90 degrees.

**Example 1** (https://yuchenw.shinyapps.io/Corner_Input_Example1/)

```
# Load the packages
library(shiny)

# User Interface
ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput(inputId = "Number", label = "A numericInput with round corner", value = NA),
  selectInput(inputId = "Select", label = "A selectInput with round corner", choices = 1:3)
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
}

# Run the app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Example 2** (https://yuchenw.shinyapps.io/Corner_Input_Example2/)

```
# Load the packages
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

# User Interface
ui <- dashboardPage(
    header = dashboardHeader(title = ""),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem(
          text = "Example",
          tabName = "tab1"
        )
      )
    ),
    body = dashboardBody(
      tabItems(
        tabItem(
          tabName = "tab1",
          numericInput(inputId = "Number", label = "A numericInput with 90-degree corner", value = NA),
          selectInput(inputId = "Select", label = "A selectInput with round corner", choices = 1:3)
        )
      )
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output, session){
}

# Run the app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@MistaPrime is correct that this is a border-radius CSS issue. One more thing to note is that `numericInput` is styled by `.form-control`, while `selectInput` is styled by `.selectizeInput`, so you will need to modify both. Here's the modified UI:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

    tags$head(
        tags$style(
            HTML(
                "
                .form-control {
                    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
                }

                .selectize-input {
                    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
                }
                "
            )
        )
    ),

  numericInput(inputId = "Number", label = "A numericInput with round corner", value = NA),
  selectInput(inputId = "Select", label = "A selectInput with round corner", choices = 1:3)
)
```

[image]

To actually answer your question as to why shinydashboard does this--I'm not sure, but it might just be the default behaviour provided by the browser.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it is bootstrap's CSS which adds a value of 4px to the corner radius.
To remove that add this to your CSS:

```
.form-control {
    border-radius: 0px;
}
```

Alternatively you can add 4px border radius to your other site:

```
.form-control {
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Comment: Great answer. Thank you very much. I decided to upvote your answer but accept heds1's answer because he or she shows the complete working example code. As a layman of CSS and HTML, I need to know which tags to modify and how to add to the R script, but like heds1 mentioned, your answer is correct and helpful.