# How to change the width and height of verbatimTextOutput in Shiny and Shinydashboard

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

In this example, I would like to make the width of the height of the `verbatimTextOutput` (**Text output no.1**) as the same as the `textInput` (**Text input no.1**). My ultimate goal is to make the appearance of the `textInput` and `verbatimTextOutput` completely the same. To achieve this, I have asked several questions as how to change the corner angle ([Why shinydashboard changes the corner of a numericInput from round to 90 degree?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58293603/7669809)), and how to change the font family of `verbatimTextOutput` ([How to change the font family of verbatimTextOutput to be the same as the input in Shiny and Shinydashboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58454087/7669809)). Changing the width and height is the final piece of the puzzle.

I also demonstrated a workaround as **Text output no. 2**, which is a `textInput` but in read-only mode as this answer shows (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58585251/7669809). However, I think this strategy is too complicated. It would be great if I can directly modify the width and height of `verbatimTextOutput`.

[image]

**Code**

```
# Load the packages
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

# User Interface
ui <- dashboardPage(
  header = dashboardHeader(title = ""),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem(
        text = "Example",
        tabName = "tab1"
      )
    )
  ),
  body = dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "tab1",

        tags$head(
          tags$style(
            HTML(
                "
                .form-control {
                    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
                }

                #txt1_out {
                font-family:  'Source Sans Pro','Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
                font-size: 14px;
                }

                "
            )
          ),
          tags$script("
            Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('selectText', function(message) {
              $('#txt2_out').prop('readonly', true);
            });
            ")
        ),
        column(
          width = 4,
          textInput(inputId = "txt1", label = "Text input no.1", value = "abcde12345"),
          strong("Text output no.1"),
          verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "txt1_out", placeholder = TRUE),
          textInput(inputId = "txt2", label = "Text input no.2", value = "abcde12345"),
          textInput(inputId = "txt2_out", label = "Text output no.2")
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$txt1_out <- renderText({
    input$txt1
  })
  observeEvent(input$txt2, {
    updateTextInput(session, inputId = "txt2_out", value = input$txt2)
    session$sendCustomMessage("selectText", "select")
  })
}

# Run the app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you check styles for `textInput`, you will find `width`, `max-width` and `padding` details.
2. I don't fully follow your question but if you want to wrap text then you can do this using `white-space: pre-wrap;`

So putting all of these in `HTML`, your `tags$style` will be something like:

```
tags$head(
  tags$style(
    HTML(
      "
        .form-control {
            border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
        }

        #txt1_out {
        font-family:  'Source Sans Pro','Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        width: 300px; 
        max-width: 100%;
        padding: 6px 12px; 
        white-space: pre-wrap;
        }

        "
    )
  )
)
```

[image]

[image]